# Display sensor value from Arduino using VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, arduino

I am trying to create an application to display moisture sensor value from Arduino using VB .NET. I would like to display the sensor value in Label1.Text but it seems like it doesn't always show the correct value.

I also tried to display the values to RichTextBox and it could display the correct value. For example, if the reading values is 1023, the value displayed in RichTextBox1 is 1023 but in Label1 is 23, or 023, or sometimes 3.

Any help with this?

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    ReceivedText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())
End Sub

Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String)
    If Me.RichTextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim x As New SetTextCallBack(AddressOf ReceivedText)
        Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
    Else
        RichTextBox1.Text &= [text]
        Label1.Text = Val([text])
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `Val` to set the `Text` property of your `Label1`?

`Val` returns the numbers contained in a string as a numeric value and stops reading the string at the first character it cannot recognize as part of a number.

**E.g:**

```
Dim valResult As Double 
' The following line of code sets valResult to 2457.
valResult = Val("2457")
' The following line of code sets valResult to 2457.
valResult = Val(" 2 45 7")
' The following line of code sets valResult to 24.
valResult = Val("24 and 57")
```

If you are receiving the read value as string...

```
Label1.Text = text
```

Comment: I've tried this but still doesn't work. I use ReadLines() instead of ReadExisting(), made few changes, and now my problem solved. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

So I've found the solution for my problem. I used ReadLine() instead of ReadExisting() and made some string operation.

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    readbuffer = SerialPort1.ReadLine()
    Me.Invoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf ReceivedText))
End Sub

Public Sub ReceivedText(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim read As Decimal
    read = readbuffer.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "")
    Label1.Text = read
End Sub
```

.